# Why does my script break when I "use" another script?

Tags: applescript

I have a script saved as scpt in Script Libraries. When I try to invoke handlers from this script, I noticed the other statements break. Is there a way to make both work? (Handler from "use"d script, and the other statements). Example below:

yo.scpt

```
to test(message)
     log message
end test
```

client script

```
use yo : script "yo"
set the clipboard to "14" -- fails because of line 1 
test(the clipboard)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this out…

[By default, when one or more use statements are added to a script, support for scripting additions must be manually enabled by adding another use statement concerning scripting additions:](https://macosxautomation.com/mavericks/usestatement/index.html)

```
use yo : script "yo"
use scripting additions

set the clipboard to "14" -- fails because of line 1 
yo's test(the clipboard)
```

Comment: I've written a lot of AppleScripts since last year and scripting additions is something I couldn't understand. Now I realized that it is on by default and have been using it unknowingly. Thank you for your answer and for sharing the link to its source.